# Gremlin query that returns key/value list where key is the vertex ID and value is value of a specific property

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am starting to learn graph databases and have hit a small snag with a query in the Gremlin query language for a proof of concept.

Say I have a vertex that represents a specific type of bolt and each of the properties represent a material and cost that the bolt is available in.

```
id: bolt-123,
label: part,
properties: [
    { steel : 0.05 },
    { aluminum : 0.02 },
    { iron : 0.03 },
    { plastic : 0.01 }
]
```

I would like to be able to get a list of all bolts and their cost that are made out of plastic. With my currently limited knowledge of Gremlin, I have been able to come up with the following query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('part').has('plastic').project('key', 'value').by('id').by('plastic')
```

which results in

```
[ { "key": "bolt-123", "value": 0.01 },
  { "key": "bolt-456", "value": 0.02 } ]
```

While this query makes perfect sense to me, I am hoping to flatten this out a little bit more so that I could have:

```
[ { "bolt-123", 0.01 },
  { "bolt-456", 0.02 } ]
```

Thanks for helping a Gremlin newbie out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want the values of the `Map` you can append `select(values)` to the end of that traversal and it will drop the keys. I'll use the "modern" graph as an example:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('k','v').by(id).by('name').select(values)
==>[1,marko]
==>[2,vadas]
==>[3,lop]
==>[4,josh]
==>[5,ripple]
==>[6,peter]
```

Of course, if you don't need the `Map` then I wouldn't bother to `project()` it in the first place, just create the `List` of values instead:

```
gremlin> g.V().map(union(id(),values('name')).fold())
==>[1,marko]
==>[2,vadas]
==>[3,lop]
==>[4,josh]
==>[5,ripple]
==>[6,peter]
```

If you want the exact output you presented you could coerce the `List` to a `Map` with `group()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   map(union(id(),values('name')).
......2>       fold().
......3>       group().
......4>         by(limit(local,1)).
......5>         by(tail(local)))
==>[1:marko]
==>[2:vadas]
==>[3:lop]
==>[4:josh]
==>[5:ripple]
==>[6:peter]
```

it's basically taking each `List` and taking the key for the `Map` from the first item in the list with `limit(local,1)` and then taking the value from the second item in the list with `tail(local)`.

Of course, it occurs to me now that if your "id" is truly unique then you could omit the `union()` and just do `group()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().group().by(id()).by(values('name').unfold())
==>[1:marko,2:vadas,3:lop,4:josh,5:ripple,6:peter]
```

Note that I purposefully did `by(values('name').unfold())` instead of `by('name')` because the latter would wrap the result in a `List`.

Comment: That is certainly much closer to what I would like (and gives me more operations to look into), but I was hoping to have it in JSON format so that I could easily deserialize the results into a .NET collection without having to loop through the returned 2D array. I'll keep looking, but any thoughts?

Comment: you can coerce the list pairs to maps with `group()` - i've updated my answer - should be just what you want now.

Comment: Thank you, this certainly looks like what I would need and gives me a lot more to learn about how query operators work and chain together. I'm still learning how to query data for various access scenarios first , then build a Proof of Concept app to use those queries.